# index out of bound exception while accessing vector elements

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


    int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    { vector <int> a,b;
      int i,n,m,k;
      bool cond=true;
     cin>>n;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         cin>>m;
         a.push_back(m);
     }
     for(i=1;i<n-1;i++)
     {
         if(a.at(i)==a.at(i+1))
            a.erase(a.begin()+i);
     }
     n=a.size();
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to delete all repetitions of consecutive numbers.
This program throws an "out of bounds" error. 
Is there any logical error, or could you suggest some better algorithm?

Comment: "why is the program throwing me an error of out of bounds????" Hmm maybe because you 're trying to access out of bounds?

Comment: `for(i=1;i<n-1;i++)` If you erase items there no longer will be n items.

Comment: Erasing elements from the vector changes it's size, hence you're going out of bounds. Consider to change `n` accordingly (`--n`).

Comment: Always iterate backwards when deleting elements in the "naive way", it'll still be O(n^2), but at least you'll avoid "shifting indexes".

Comment: (that being said, the proper solution is O(n), with the classical "read pointer/write pointer" loop, or more simply, using `std::remove` and its relatives)

Comment: Construct a set from vector and then assign the data back to vector.

Comment: A good debugger could be very helpful in finding the problem here... Have you tried one?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? The question is clear enough and even has short and to-the-point sample code. That's better than most questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing out of bounds since after erasing an element your container is now one element shorter than the number of times you are iterating.

In any case; you can solve your problem in two lines if you just use what's already available in the standard library:

```
auto last = std::unique(a.begin(), a.end());
a.erase(last, a.end());
```

See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique